# Undefined variable: provinces (View: E:\XXXXXXXXXXX\create.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-5.6

what is the wrong with this Note : i'm using Laravel 5.6
My Guess is that their something wrong with the "@foreach"

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                   @foreach ($provinces as $key => $value)
                                 <label for="">Your Provinces</label>
                                  <select class="form-control" name="provinces" id="provinces">
                                   <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Provinces ===</option>
                                 <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
                                    
                                    </select>
                                        </div>
                                     @endforeach

it tells me undefined variable provinces and here is my Controller 


<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
   
    public function provinces(){
      $provinces = Provinces::all();
      return view('posts.create', compact('provinces'));
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

By this controller, have you used `$provinces = Provinces::all();` without using model file ?

Ex: `Use App\Models\Provinces;`

Comment: thanks for your replay , yeah i used $provinces = Provinces::all(); in my controller and i have a model called Provinces.php and that's the code of it 
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Provinces extends Model
{
    //
}
what do you mean with   Use App\Models\Provinces;

Comment: By usual, you have to include model `Provinces.php` file into Controller to define the class `Provinces` so that you can call `::all()` . May be you could `dd($provinces);` after `$provinces = Provinces::all();` to show what data received .

Comment: Ah you mean like use App\Models\Provinces; I did that. Actually but nothing changed  but what do you mean  dd($provinces); ....... It tells me undefined variable

Comment: "Undefined variable" means ` $provinces = Provinces::all();` was wrong. Could you show me Namespace of Provinces.php file

Comment: that's weird cause the same code and the same everything works without any problem on Laravel version 5.5.*  but on laravel version 5.6.* i get that error which is   Undefined variable anyway that's the namespace for Provinces.php

namespace App;

Comment: You might try including `App\Provinces; ` the controller would be ` `namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Provices;
class CountryController extends Controller`

Comment: thanks ,but i already did and the same result anyway  their is another error which is "Class CountryController does not exist" While its exists which is inside the controller mentioned above "at my question" i can't fix it do you have any help about that ,
Thanks In advance

Comment: hi again i solved the error "Class CountryController does not exist" and the error of undefined variable by changing "posts.create" to "posts/create" in my Routs web.php file but is that the write way to solve this

Comment: Update :(  the error still exists undefined variable i think the mean reason for this is Routs stuff i mean web.php file please can you take a look at it i've attached it here
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SLdJOWihzotmECeZHAWQIb9KXAQ3DfpA 
where i should place 
Route::get('post.create','CountryController@provinces');
Route::get('/json-regencies','CountryController@regencies');
Route::get('/json-districts', 'CountryController@districts');
Route::get('/json-village', 'CountryController@villages');

in the file web.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: we should put it in group of right namespace and it will be automaticly catch the controller class - by usual

Comment: ah you mean something like  ['namespace:App\Http\Controller']   
Thanks for your time

Comment: I thinkl so. we put files in right namespaces and include them into other to be correctly called .